# Win32 C++ writing to serial freezes the program after a while

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port

I added a serial port writing to my code and now it freezes after few tenths of iterations. Few minutes it works just it should. If I remove serial port related lines, it will run smoothly forever. Im using Visualstudio. Can anyone spot the problem?

```
int main() {
    HANDLE hSerial;
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    
    // Open the serial port
    hSerial = CreateFile(L"COM1", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cout << "Error opening serial port" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Set the serial port parameters
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    if (GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams) == 0) {
        std::cout << "Error getting serial port state" << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }
    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
    if (SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams) == 0) {
        std::cout << "Error setting serial port state" << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }

    // Send the serial message
    DWORD dwBytesWritten;
    char message[] = "c";
    WriteFile(hSerial, message, sizeof(message) - 1, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);  

    

    while (stop == 0) {
        
        WriteFile(hSerial, "x", sizeof(message) - 1, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 7) {
            i++;
            //some code that works fine without serial port writings
        }
        
        WriteFile(hSerial, "y", sizeof(message) - 1, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

        i = 0;
        while (i < 7) {
            i++;
            //some code that works fine without serial port writings
        }
    }
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

I have made the code as simple as I possible can. Still it has some serious problem.

Comment: the freeze might be appearing because of the port getting locked. Introducing some timeout limit  by SetCommTimeouts [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcommtimeouts] might help. 
which of the std::cout statements gets printed in freeze situation ?

Comment: Check if each WriteFile call was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you will try to write before the first call is not finished; the buffer can be full, check PurgeComm function.
Try also to implement an event sequence. (WaitCommEvent)

Comment: This was it! Big thank to You! Added these after write and now it runs smoothly:

Comment: `code`
//Empty the output buffer
        PurgeComm(hSerial, PURGE_TXCLEAR | PURGE_RXCLEAR);
        //ensure that the contents are transmitted
        FlushFileBuffers(hSerial);
`/code`

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading the values on the other side of the serial? I know that for example on a lot of the cheaper knockoff FTDI USB-Serial chips which are common on Arduino-likes, they have a small (4kB) buffer, and will simply block the call if the buffer is full.

Another thing to consider if the blocking itself is your biggest issue might be to check out the `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag in [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea). It won't solve the issue of communication ceasing, but if your biggest concern is simply not blocking other parts of the program until communication is ready that might be an option.

Comment: Since you can use `WaitFor...` on ports, overlapped I/O kind of seems like a redundant feature. Rather than using overlapped I/O, consider using multithreading, which is the correct way to implement this to begin with.

Comment: Yes I'm reading with genuine Arduino Uno, well quessed hodahle :) I added "Serial.flush();" to Arduino code even it didn't solve the problem entirely this time. Thank you.

Comment: Not `Serial.flush()`, `Serial.read()`. See the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/flush/). `Serial.flush()` only ensures your outgoing serial data is fully written, it doesn't do anything with the input buffer. You need to read it to clear it, even if you just discard it, e.g. `while(Serial.available()){Serial.read();}`. See if that helps.